# Specifying timeout for reading messages from activemq queue using camel

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am using camel to read messages from an activemq queue, process it and post it to another queue. The route looks as follows:

```
from("jms:incoming.queue")
.process(new MyProcessor())
.to("jms:outgoing.queue");
```

I need to specify a timeout such that if there are no messages in "incoming.queue" for more than 3 minutes, I would like to stop the route. I can use OnCompletion() but it gets called after each message. I can specify timeout for sending message to "outgoing.queue". Is there a way I can specify a timeout such that if there are no message for more than 3 minutes in the "incoming.queue", I can stop the route?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Why would you need to stop the route which is not active for more than 3 minutes? You could write last processing time somewhere and check it with other route pushed with timer component.

Comment: @white - The requirement is that the messages in the "incoming.queue" needs to be processed during off hours, say at 8:00PM in the evening. The route needs to process all the messages in the queue at that time. Once processing all the messages, the route needs to be stopped so that it does not start processing the messages as soon as they starting arriving in the queue next day. The route needs to be started again in the evening at 8:00PM. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

two options I can think of...

1. use a [CronScheduledRoutePolicy](http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html) to start/stop your route automatically at specified times...

   ```
   CronScheduledRoutePolicy myPolicy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();
   myPolicy.setRouteStartTime("0 20 * * * ?");
   myPolicy.setRouteStopTime("0 0 * * * ?");

   from("jms:incoming.queue")
       .routePolicy(myPolicy).noAutoStartup()
       .process(new MyProcessor())
       .to("jms:outgoing.queue");
   ```
2. use a camel-quartz route and a [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) to drain the queue on a schedule

   ```
   MyCoolBean cool = new MyCoolBean();
   cool.setProducer(template); 
   cool.setConsumer(consumer);

   from("quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+20+*+*+*+?")
       .bean(cool);

   //MyCoolBean snippet 
   while (true) {
       // receive the message from the queue, wait at most 60s
       Object msg = consumer.receiveBody("jms:incoming.queue", 60000);
       if (msg == null) {
           break;
       }
       producer.sendBody("jms:outgoing.queue", msg);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can use CronScheduledRoutePolicy to meet my requirements. The only thing is that I need to allow sufficient time before stopping the route so that all the messages in the "incoming.queue" are processed. It would have been much better if it was possible to specify a timeout for reading messages from queue and stop the route if the timeout happens.

Comment: see my updated answer...option #2 gives you more control over the timeout side, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above it appears you are just looking to start and stop the route on a schedule. You can use a quartz job to call the start and stop methods on your jms route.  You could even make the quartz logic a route as well using the quartz endpoint if you like.

Comment: Thanks. I liked using CronScheduledRoutePolicy to start and stop the route as it is a little more compact and everything could be specified as part of a single route.